# field inheritance in POS (Odoo)

Tags: odoo-10, point-of-sale

I've added the field 'limit' in 'res.partner' model in 'Sales'. Now, I want to inherit the same in my POS module during the Customer Creation.

I've included all my files(xml and js) in **manifest**.py with proper syntax.
My '.js' file is working completely fine. The problem shows in 'static/src/xml/pos.xml' file.
Here's my code of pos.xml file. No syntax error, still cant get 'limit' field in POS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template_test" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="ClientDetailsEdit">
        <t t-jquery=".client-details-right" t-operation="append">
            <div class='client-detail'>
                <span class='label'>Limit</span>
                <input class='detail limit' name='limit' value="5000" readonly="True" t-att-value='partner.limit || ""'></input>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Please, tell me if anything is wrong or missing!

Comment: Have you loaded that custom field in POS via adding that field in res.parter? Check models.js file. In that whatever field you want to add of whatever model need to defined there.

Comment: Yes, my js file is running properly. I've even verified it by generating an alert in my js file.
Only problem with the xml file

Comment: and what is the error

Comment: Use 'inside' insted of 'append'

Comment: No error, it's just not showing 'limit' field.

Comment: Can you try removing the properties value="5000" and readonly="True"?